# Smartmontools with NVMe support on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, smartctl, smart, nvme

I've just set up CentOS 7 on a server with NVMe drives, and was suprised not to be able to run `smartctl` on them:

```
# smartctl -a /dev/nvme0
/dev/nvme0: Unable to detect device type
Please specify device type with the -d option.

# smartctl -a /dev/nvme0 -d nvme
/dev/nvme0: Unknown device type 'nvme'
```

Then I noticed that CentOS ships with Smartmontools version 6.2, whereas [Smartmontools supports NVMe starting from version 6.5](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/NVMe_Support).

**How can I upgrade Smartmontools to version 6.5 on CentOS 7?**

Their [download page](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Packages) only offers Smartmontools 6.2 for CentOS 7.

Ideally, I don't want to compile from source, I would prefer a RPM, or better, a third-party repo that would include the latest Smartmontools, to get regular updates.

## Alternative

I'm also open to suggestions if you know another tool, preferably included in CentOS 7, that could allow me to get SMART info from an NVMe drive.

Comment: I make my own debs to support the latest FreeRadius...always an alternative making your own packages if need be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I found 2 alternatives.

## Getting a precompiled binary that works on CentOS 7

Even though their [packages](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Packages) page only offers Smartmontools 6.2 for CentOS 7, their [SVN builds](http://builds.smartmontools.org/) page offers binaries that do work on CentOS.

The proper archive has a `.linux` suffix, for example I chose:

> smartmontools-6.6-0-20170503-r4430.linux-x86_64.tar.gz

This archive contains a `smartctl` binary that works like a charm.

## Using the nvme command-line tool

CentOS 7 ships with an `nvme` command (the yum package is named `nvme-cli`).

It can list the NVMe drives:

```
# nvme list
```

And can read SMART info:

```
# nvme smart-log /dev/nvme0
```

And *additional* SMART info (not sure why it's split):

```
# nvme smart-log-add /dev/nvme0
```

Comment: For some reason, my systems require adding `intel` to the last command: `nvme intel smart-log-add /dev/nvme0`.

Comment: @Brian That's because `intel` is an extension, provided by a plugin. Check `nvme help` command. `nvme smart-log-add` is not intended for every disk, it is vendor-specific. For example, for my Hynix it doesn't work.